# How does this hexadecimal arithmetic work?

Tags: c, pointers, hex

I'm learning C pointers. I have incremented a double pointer by 1, as follows:

before -> `ptr_double =0x0128`

then I incremented it by 1, and then the address stored in ptr_double increases by 8 bytes, that is `0x0128` + 8 which gives `0x0130`.

I'm unable to understand how arithmetically `0x0130` comes.

I know this is probably a basic question, but I'm having difficulty understanding this. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: It's simple hexadecimal addition.Counting goes as follows: 0x0129 ,0x012A 0x012B,0x012C,0x012D,0x012E,0x012F,0x0130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a pointer to `double` like `double* ptr_double;`, which has its value `0x128`, then you increment it `++ptr_double;` (which makes the pointer *jump* with a `sizeof(double)`, which in this case is `8`). The address is in hexadecimal (base 16), so

```
0x128 + 0x8 = 0x130
```

Remember that hexadecimals belong to the range `0,1,...,9,A,B,C,D,E,F`, so `0x8 + 0x8 = 10`.

Comment: yap  you're correct my problem is im unable to understand the arithmetic step, why it cannot be 0x128 + 0x8 = 0x136

Comment: @VenVaru: You want to read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: @vsoftco could you explain more please ?

Comment: After `0x128` follows `0x129, 0x12A, 0x12B, 0x12C, 0x12D, 0x12E, 0x12F`, then `0x130`. See @ARBY's comment also.